# How to print the page and close the Print window in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Selenium fresher:

I used the following code in selenium to open the print window but it doesn't work

```
Keyboard keyboard = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getKeyboard();
keyboard.pressKey(Keys.ENTER);  
keyboard.pressKey(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "p"));
```

And i used the following code to open the Print window and it works

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("print()");
```

My Question is how to print the page and close the print window?

Comment: The print window closes when you press print...

Comment: @JackBashford, Yes you are right but i can't able to click the print or cancel button in the print window. i have try this code but it not clicking on the print / cancel button ` driver.findElement(By.className("cancel-button")).click();` `driver.findElement(By.className("action-button")).click();`. Please suggest how to click the print and cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>kiosk-printing</kbd> chrome option to complete the print without interacting with print window.

Here is the snippet that you can use.

**Java:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk-printing");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.print();");
```

**Python:**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

You will see the print window for a fraction of seconds and then it will close automatically. Then you can see the printing job in your default printer.